# Div won't show up unless it has display of list-item

Tags: css, sass

This is code for the div

```
    width: 110px;
    height: 10px;
    background: #ffff;
    border-radius: 30px;
    margin-top: -10px;
```

and this is how it displays it

[image: div]

But if display is set as list-item it shows up,any other display won't work

[image: div showed up]

I'm not sure what i messed up,and why height shows 0

Comment: Does your `<div>` happen to be a direct child of an `ul`? If so, note that's illegal HTML. Since your issue is related to styling, you should provide a *runnable* [mcve]. Without one, there is no way to determine the exact cause of your issue.

Answer (score 1):

`height` only works on `block` box, and `display: list-item` uses `block` box by default. I guess your original css may contain `inline`-type display and cause `height` not working. Here is an example to show the results in different cases:

```css
.bar {
  width: 110px;
  height: 10px;
  background: #ffff;
  border-radius: 30px;
  margin-top: -10px;
}

.display-block {
  display: block;
}

.display-inline {
  display: inline;
}

.display-list-item {
  display: list-item;
}
```

```html
<body style="background: #999;padding: 10px">

<div>Div (default display is "block")</div>
<div class="bar"></div>

<div>Span (default display is "inline")</div>
<span class="bar"></span>

<div>With "inline" display</div>
<div class="bar display-inline"></div>

<div>With "block" display</div>
<div class="bar display-block"></div>

<div>With "list-item" display</div>
<div class="bar display-list-item"></div>

</body>
```

Ref: MDN - Introduction to the CSS basic box model - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Box_Model/Introduction_to_the_CSS_box_model#content_area

Another possible case is that there are other `display`, `height` or `max-height` settings in the current css hierarchy and override the original ones. You may check the css applied to the target div is what you want.